# File opened with readfile is not being shown

Tags: php, get, readfile

```
<p>
<?php
$filename = $_GET['package'];
echo readfile("$filename.txt");
?></p>
```

This is a part of my html, and I want to use this url to read the filename of a txt:

```
http://example.com/something.html?package=new
```

if I am using this, the html must show the contents of new.txt, but nothing.

I've set `error_reporting(-1)` but there is no error.

The URL is http://repo.cydie.com/depictions/2.html just see the source code

What was my error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need no echo for readfile. [`readfile()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) will output the contents directly

```
readfile("$filename.txt");
```

Manual:

> Reads a file and writes it to the output buffer.

Note that this causes problems as `readfile()` will return the number of bytes read from the file. So your content - if exist - will look like:

```
hello world
12
```

(note the linefeed, that's why 12, not 11)

---

But this doesn't cause the problem, that the file isn't found. You should check if `$filename` really exists!

Comment: @Cydie What gives you `var_dump($filename);`?

Comment: And what gives you `var_dump(file_exists($filename . '.txt'));` ?

Comment: the answer with extension's was good.

Comment: Looks like it is working now? :)

Comment: yes, but in this site looks like they are doing something similar with html, (i mean the url): `http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/forum.html?id=1`

Comment: Yes you can configure your web server to parse other extensions as php as well. but this is not the default configuration.

Comment: ohh ok, that was the best answer today ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have done wrong concatenation here

change this

```
echo readfile("$filename.txt");
```

to

```
readfile($filename . ".txt");
```

Comment: Not true, OPs' *interpolation* is correct

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<p>
<?php
  $filename = $_GET['package'].".txt";
  echo readfile($filename);
?></p>
```

Comment: Didn't worked :/ Idk why